# Reading Usenet newsgroups on any computer

Tags: usenet, google-groups, newsgroups

Is there any solution, beside Google Groups, to read Usenet groups (and post to them) from any computer?  I am looking for something that is closer to a newsreader, with scores, mark-thread-as-read, ignore-thread, etc.  I would like to be able to access this service from any computer, including my iPhone.

Are there web-based newsreaders that I could install on a server at home?  Or some company that offers this kind of service?  I does not have to be free, although it would not hurt...

Thanks.

Comment: Off topic for Super User. Questions about web applications should be directed to http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'll post my question there too. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

As for services, the servers you connect to for finding news, you can pay [Super News](http://supernews.com) or [Giga News](http://www.giganews.com) for access to Usenet/Alternet.

As for web clients, I think both SuperNews and GigaNews have their own web interfaces. Google Groups used to allow you to set a non-Google account up. Basically you read news through Google Groups and you post items from their interface through SuperNews or GigaNews. I haven't done Usenet in a few years so I'm not sure if it still works like this.

In addition there are several newsreaders you can install at home. Most mail clients such as [Thunderbird](http://www.mozilla.com/G) have newsreaders built in.

I'm sorry if this is an incomplete answer but it I hope it will get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: SuperNews and GigaNews seem mostly oriented toward 'high-volume' usenet users, while I'm only interested in a dozen text-only groups.  And I want to avoid mail clients, because I would not be able to access it from other computers, or my iPhone.